# UI for displaying incoming/sent sms in android

Tags: android, sms

I am including a messaging feature in my app.But I am not sure about how the incoming/sent messages can be displayed. Can anyone help me out with how the UI for the messaging apps are built e.g. [goSMSPro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms&hl=en) ?
I could think of using a LinearLayout inside ScrollView and add TextViews as the messages are received or sent, or using a ListView. Is this approach correct, if not is there any better approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First learn the basics correctly and search before you ask a question.

Comment: I apologize Dinesh. I wanted to say LinearLayout inside Scrollview. I had searched for how UI for messaging can be implemented, but I did not find anything helpful. So, I posted the question. If you know any link which I can refer to, can you please post it?

Comment: Learn about Listview what you need is there.

Comment: Ok. I know what a ListView is and how it is used. I had thought of it. But I had some concerns about using it. Anyways, I will look for trade offs between both. Thanks for your time!

Comment: What are your concerns about listview?

Comment: Whenever a new message comes in or is sent, the listview will need to be refreshed by updating the datasource and calling notifyDatasetChanged(). I also know about optimization about listView. But I am not clear about will it affect performance if the whole listView is refreshed for every single message. Please tell me if I am misunderstanding something here instead of vote down, plz.

Comment: ListView has to be notified whenever there is a new data set and it shouldn't affect the performance very much because at the most any device can receive only one message at a time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will go ahead with ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me, using adding TextViews inside a LinerLayout, whenever a new message is received, would *not be the easiest* way.  Use a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) to display the messages. ListViews are meant for such purposes only and would reduce your headache a lot. If you want to show the messages in the form of a conversation, you can align the text in each row according to the sender and the receiver.

Whenever a new message is received, just call **`notifyDatasetChanged()`** on the ListView and the messages would get updated.

Comment: I reckon that is what I conveyed.

Comment: Thanks Swayam. Came to same conclusion after discussing with Dinesh.

Comment: Yes, @DineshVenkata , that's exactly what you said. It's just that I happened to see your comments just now. :)

Comment: @andro : Good luck ahead! Cheers! :)